# AOSP , Error while building android Source code on Mac

Tags: android, compilation, android-source, building

I am building Android source code on MacOS 10.12.6.
Android Version is 7.1.1, I have faced few issues and till now i am able to resolve all of it.

Right now I am facing issue with "lunch" command following is the error :-

```
-bash: Saving: command not found
-bash: ...saving: command not found
-bash: ...completed.: command not found

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_arm'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Where did you refer the steps for building AOSP in Mac

Comment: https://source.android.com/setup/initializing#setting-up-a-mac-os-x-build-environment

Comment: have you run this command: $ source/build/envsetup.sh? before lunch command.

You are in sudo mode?

Comment: yes I did but not is sudo mode

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this error because the folder name (where i downloaded AOSP code) was having space "MY AOSP" after changing it to "MY_AOSP" issue got fixed.